# Smoothness of tangential and normal projections

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm studying John M. Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds, p. 17

Let's see the next image

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can't understand the underlined statement. How can we deduce the smoothness of $\pi ^{\top}$ and $\pi^{\bot}$ from the formula for an adapted orthonormal frame?

My first attempt : My first attempt is applying the above Bundle homomorphism characterization Lemma.

First, let's consider only $\pi^{\top}$. The case of $\pi^{\bot}$ may be similar.

As in the proof, for $p \in M$, there is a smooth orthonormal frame $(E_{1},\cdots,E_{m})$ that is adapted to $U$ on some neighborhood $\tilde{U}$ of $p$ in $\tilde{M}$

Now, consider the restriction $\bar{\pi}^{\top}$ :
$\pi^{-1}(\tilde{U} \cap U) \to \pi^{'-1}(\tilde{U}\cap U)$ of the $\pi^{\top}$, where
$\pi :T\tilde{M} |_{M} \to M$ and $\pi^{'} : TM \to M $ are the canonical projections.

Now, let $\Gamma(\pi^{-1}(\tilde{U} \cap U))$, and $\Gamma(\pi^{'-1}(\tilde{U} \cap U))$ be the
space of global sections (over $\tilde{U} \cap U$).

Define $\mathcal{F} $ : $\Gamma(\pi^{-1}(\tilde{U} \cap U)) \to \Gamma(\pi^{'-1}(\tilde{U} \cap U))$ as $\mathcal{F}(\sigma)(p) := (\bar{\pi}^{\top} \circ \sigma )(p)$.

Then, at least over $\tilde{U} \cap U$, we can show that $\mathcal{F}$ is linear over $C^{\infty}(\tilde{U} \cap U)$ by the formula for $\pi^{\top}$ in terms of an adapted orthonormal frame, as in the proof.

So, by the bundle homomorphism characterization Lemma, there is a smooth bundle homomorphism
$F : \pi^{-1}(\tilde{U} \cap U) \to \pi^{'-1}(\tilde{U}\cap U)$ over $\tilde{U} \cap U$ such that $\mathcal{F} (\sigma)=F \circ \sigma$ for all $\sigma\in \Gamma(\pi^{-1}(\tilde{U} \cap U))$. And from this and by the definition of $\mathcal{F}$, we can check that  $\bar{\pi}^{\top}=F$(maybe?). So $\bar{\pi}^{\top}$ is smooth.

But this argument seems to works only over $\tilde{U} \cap U$ not M. How can we deduce that $\pi^{\top}$ is smooth? Certain gluing mechanism involved? Or, is there any sufficient condition(characterization) for smoothness of bundle map?

Comment: Hint: Look at Lemma A.33 in Appendix A.

Comment: You mean, the "local frame criterion for smoothness? "Uhm.. What is relation between the lemma and target statement ; smoothness ? Perhaps, can we try to use the "smoothness is local" in your 'Introduction to smooth manifolds - Proposition.2.6 ', continuing my argument? In your point of view, it seems possible? Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Yes, of course. If . If you can show that a map is smooth in a neighborhood of each point, then it is smooth.

Comment: Ok. Thanks!)  :)